# World-renowned for having many natural wonders

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge, geography

> 1. Ancient tombs perplex urban Bonnie (11)
> 2. Magic sleek hill mixed is small island (14)
> 3. Small island's hidden twin is Moroccan (7)
> 4. Dramatic sound and additional grotto are underground site (11)
> 5. Ooh, runic altar stirs up a mountain! (13)
> 6. Headless woman and painful marking inside satellite mountain (12)
> 7. Rock formation Goliaths make a road happen (14)
> 8. Richard and Robertson owned by heartless relative are rocky landforms (13)
> 9. Gung-ho heal disfigured lake (10)
> 10. Grieve Spanish website mountain range (7)

Where are we?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ancient tombs perplex urban Bonnie (11)

> This is Brú na Bóinne (rearranged urban Bonnie), which are ancient tombs in Ireland.

Magic sleek hill mixed is small island (14)

> This is Skellig Michael (mixed Magic sleek hill), a small twin-peaked island in County Kerry, Ireland.

Small island's hidden twin is Moroccan (7)

> This is the small island of Inis Mor, hidden in twIN IS MORoccan.

Dramatic sound and additional grotto are underground site (11)

> Dunmore Cave is an underground site (dun dun dunnnn... + more  <strike>cowbell</strike>  cave)

Ooh, runic altar stirs up a mountain! (13)

> The tallest mountain in Ireland is Carrauntoohil, (ooh runic altar stirred up).

Headless woman and painful marking inside satellite mountain (12)

> Mount Brandon, first climbed by St. Brendan the Navigator. ("AUNT" - A = "UNT" + painful marking "BRAND" inside satellite "MOON" = MO + UNT + BRAND + ON).

Rock formation Goliaths make a road happen (14)

> Giant's Causeway, a rock formation in Northern Ireland (Goliaths are Giants, they cause the way).

Richard and Robertson owned by heartless relative are rocky landforms (13)

> Cliffs of Moher, a series of rocky landforms (Cliff Richard and Cliff Robertson + MOTHER - T).

Gung-ho heal disfigured lake (10)

> The largest freshwater lake in Ireland is Lough Neagh (gung-ho heal, disfigured).

Grieve Spanish website mountain range (7)

> This is the Mournes mountain range, (MOURN + .ES)

I'd imagine that we are in

> Ireland!

Comment: Holy cow, and I thought this one was going to be more difficult. All correct!